# Remove a file within a while loop

Tags: python

I am trying to delete a file inside a while loop. This is the code I am running

```
while 1:
    tts = gTTS(text="Hello", lang='en', slow=False)
    tts.save("file.mp3")
    playsound.playsound("file.mp3", True)
    os.remove("file.mp3")
```

However the file is never removed until the while loop is stopped. Is there any way to remove the file while still running the while loop?

Comment: How do you know the file was not removed? How did you check?

Comment: "the file is never removed until the while loop is stopped". Well, you are in an infinite, recreating the file after it's deleted

Comment: Because you keep remaking it with the same name? How do you know it's not being removed and remade?

Comment: If `os.remove` fails, it should raise an error. Is it crashing on that? That would explain why it's "still there". How does your loop stop anyways?

Comment: Are there breakpoints in Python? A web search suggests that there are. Add a breakpoint inside of your `while` loop, after the call to remove(), and see if the file has actually been removed in the directory.

Answer (score 2):

A file is created when you call `tts.save("file.mp3")` and deleted by `os.remove("file.mp3")`. Since your `while` loop is running continuously, it's created just after it is destroyed. This process happens so fast that you can't see the file's deletion/creation with your eyes while observing the directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible that the file *is* being erased, but then it is being recreated in the next iteration of the loop without you noticing. Try renaming the file so that you know if it is deleted or not.

I also recommend not doing an infinite cycle.

Answer (score 0):

As [Vineet Jain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45987854) and [Dayana](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45987916) mentioned, you are probably deleting the files, but faster than you can see.

You can, of course, verify this for yourself. Instead of:

```
while 1:
```

you can use a `for` loop with range() to generate different names for your file. You will have something like:

```
from gtts import gTTS
import playsound
import os

for item in range(1, 10):
    tts = gTTS(text="Hello", lang='en', slow=False)
    filename = str(item) + ".mp3"
    tts.save(filename)
    playsound.playsound(filename, True)
    os.remove(filename)
```

With this, you will be able to see the file being created and deleted inside the folder.